# Not able to run windows scheduler from Azure Devops Pipeline. Getting error like The WinRM client cannot process the request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, window, winrm

I got the below error:
**`[error]System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server MYSERVER01 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.`
`If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts.`
`Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`**

*##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.*

```
- task: StopWindowsScheduledTask@2
                inputs:
                  ScheduledTaskFullName: 'TestService_Development'
                  ComputerNames: 'MYSERVER01'
                  Username: 'MYSERVER01\admin'
                  Password: 'xxxxxxx'
                  AuthenticationOptions: 'Default'
                  ProtocolOptions: 'HTTP'
```

I have looked for few solution https://www.hemalekanayake.com/2016/07/solved-winrm-client-cannot-process.html but not worked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide this also we used using 80, 443, 5986 port in proxy but not  worked. Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

```
steps:
- task: WinRM - IIS Web App Management
  displayName: 'Stop $(AppName) Application Pool on $(webserver)'
  inputs:
    machinesList: '$(webserver)'
    AdminUserName: '$(username)'
    AdminPassword: '$(password)'
    ActionIISWebsite: StopWebsite
    StartStopWebsiteName: 'UserAPI'
```

Comment: the above yaml task works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.